# Store a word to use later in MS Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I am using MS Word 2007. Here I would like to a word. Later I would like to use that word using short cut key.

How can I do that??

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about something like an extended clipboard that holds multiple entries to select and paste?

Comment: Actually I would like to press a key/keys and which type a predefined word. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I misunderstood your question in my first answer.

You can use macros.

Record a keyboard macro of typing out the word and assign a keyboard shortcut to it.